# GWT - Tips Needed - Check and set parameter on the session. Is this the right way?

Tags: session, gwt

Im made a sort of autentication on my web application using GWT. So i make these functions in the GWTServiceImpl Class :

```
public class PageMenuLogin extends FlowPanel {
    public PageMenuLogin() {
        PageMenuLogin.getService().isSetSession(new AsyncCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                InlineLabel err=new InlineLabel();
                err.setText("Errore Di Connessione");
                PageMenuLogin.this.add(err);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                if(result.compareTo("")==0) {
                    designLogin();
                } else {
                    designLogout(result);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public final void designLogin() {
        final InlineLabel menu_err=new InlineLabel("");
        menu_err.setStyleName("menu_err");
        this.add(menu_err);        

        Button menu_login_button=new Button("Login");
        this.add(menu_login_button);

        menu_login_button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                getService().checkLogin("nickname", "password", new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        menu_err.setText("Comunicazione Fallita");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                        if (result) {
                            // I LOAD THE PROFILE PAGE
                        } else {
                            menu_err.setText("Username e password non validi");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

********************************************************************************

public class GWTServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GWTService {
    HttpServletRequest request;
    HttpSession session;
    public String isSetSession() {
        this.request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
        this.session=this.request.getSession();

        if(this.session.getAttribute("nickname")==null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return (String)this.session.getAttribute("nickname");
        }
    }

    public boolean checkLogin(String username, String password) {
        if("i check on the database if the user exist") {
            this.session.setAttribute("nickname", value);
            return true;
        } 

        return false;
    }
}
```

On client side, i call the GWTServiceImpl functions (server side), i check the return values and i do some operations.

Is this the right way to work with session on GWT? Any suggestion/tips/helps would be appreciated :)

Thanks for your time!!!

**EDIT**

New GWTServiceImpl :

```
public class GWTServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GWTService {

    HttpSession session;

    public String isSetSession() {
        HttpSession session=getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();
        if(session.getAttribute("nickname")==null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return (String)session.getAttribute("nickname");
        }
    }

    public boolean checkLogin(String nickname, String password) {
        HttpSession session=getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();
        Database mydb=Configuration.getDatabase();
        mydb.connetti();

        // faccio md5 ed escape
        String log_check_user=nickname;
        String log_check_pass=password;

        // controllo che l'utente esista
        ArrayList<String[]> db_result=null;
        db_result=mydb.selectQuery("SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE  nickname='"+log_check_user+"' AND password='"+log_check_pass+"'");
        mydb.disconnetti();
        if(!db_result.isEmpty()) {
            session.setAttribute("nickname", nickname);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkLogout() {
        HttpSession session=getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();
        session.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it should work. I do a lot of work with GWT, although I often forego the use of the RemoteServiceServlet in favour of passing data back and forth via JSON.

A few suggestions, though. When you're calling a method or field within the same class, you don't need to include the `this` keyword. It doesn't hurt, but tends to make your code longer than it needs to be. Feel free to keep it though, if you find it makes things clearer for you.

Also, unless you've got methods that actually use the request, you don't need to create the request object; you can just do

`session = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();`

A final suggestion: Since you're using the session in more than one method, it might be a good idea to initialize it right away; So, instead of initializing it in `isSetSession()`, you could just write `HttpSession session = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();`, or initialize it in the class's constructor. As it stands now, if you happen to call `checkLogin()` before `isSetSession()`, you'll get a `NullPointerException` since `session` hasn't yet been initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your rips man, i really appreciate your help :) So, about this, yes i use it because it makes things more clear for me. About request, yes i can use the getSession directly trought getThreadLocalRequest(), good idea! And about a final suggestion, you have totally right. But if i write it on the costruction (check the code above) it doesnt work. What am I wrong? :) P.S. (OT) How can I add the text such <pre> in the comments?

Comment: I think that bit of advice I gave about the session initialization might have been incorrect. I had forgotten that often a servlet container will create the servlet once at startup, and then just reuse it. So, you probably don't want to have the session set up as a class field at all. Instead, you'll probably want to do `HttpSession session = getThreadLocalRequest.getSession()` in each method where you want to have access to the session.

Comment: Yes...that i need. So i think i need to do getThreadLocalRequest.getSession() every time in my functions :) Watch the new function in my edit, now should works :)

Comment: As far as I know, Servlets aren't thread-safe...so you could potentially have several requests using the servlet at the same time. Because of this, you shouldn't declare the HttpSession outside of a method; Otherwise, you risk one user accidentally getting access to another user's session. The easiest way to fix this is to make `session` a local variable inside each method. So, in this example, you'll want to get rid of the `HttpSession session` at the top of the class and put `HttpSession session = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();` inside both `isSetSession` and `checkLogin`

Comment: OH yeah you are right thanks! Fixed the solution :) P.s. But why i need to declare HttpSession session at the top of the class?